# In Visual Studio, when using remotebuild for Apache Cordova, Plugins folder does not populate

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015, phonegap-plugins, apache-cordova

I have an Apache Cordova application built in Visual Studio 2015.

When using remotebuild on my MacBook, everything shows up correctly in my cordovaApp/platforms/ios/[Project Name] folder except for the Plugins folder.  The folder is there, but it's empty.

When I look at the "platforms/ios/[Project Name]" folder of my Visual Studio solution, the Plugins folder is populated properly.  It's just not getting pushed to my Mac.

When a fellow developer on my team, who appears to have the same dev environment that I do, builds the same source code, the Plugins info is successfully sent to his Mac.

We compared all of the environmental settings we could think of that might impact this functionality, but nothing jumped out.

Has anyone else has this problem?  Or have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to give code example

Comment: An example of what?  This is during a normal build process when debugging to Xcode Simulator.  It is not code-specific.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the Tools for Apache Cordova for Visual Studio?

Comment: Can you try deleting the platforms directory and trying again?

Comment: @MichaelBraude Tried it...no success.

Comment: OK, I checked with the team (I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio). There was a bug with a previous version of remote build that may be causing this. Are you and the other developer using the same Mac? If not, can you try uninstalling and re-installing remote build on your Mac so that remote build gets updated? If that doesn't work, I'd like my team to work with you to resolve the issue. Please email us at vscordovatools@microsoft.com so we can set up a time to investigate.

Comment: @MichaelBraude That worked!  Thanks so much for your help.  If you want to put this text as a separate comment, I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Send a message on Twitter to the @VSCordovaTools team.  I am sure they will want to help out and see what's going on.

Comment: Michael Braude actually gave the correct answer.  I was hoping he would enter it as an answer so that I could accept it.